# Не работает keyup на элементе html

Tags: jquery, html, события, javascript

```js
$('#val-fortune-1').keyup(function() {
  $('#sumBuy').text($('#val-fortune-1').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="val-fortune-1" name="val-fortune-1" class="fortune-enter">
<span style="color: #000;" id="sumBuy">0</span>
```

При вводе в поле **val-fortune-1**, текст в **sumBuy** не меняется.
Разве не должен меняться? Хотя если изменить отслеживаемый элемент при событии **keyup** на **document**, все в порядке.

Как сделать можно, чтобы при вводе в поле **val-fortune-1**, текст менялся, без отслеживания всего документа?

**Проблема в добавлении элементов с помощью JS, т.е в процессе, а не изначально**

Comment: Может keydown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#val-fortune-1').on('keyup', function(){

});
// Или (даже лучше) делегированно
$('/*селектор_родительского_статического_элемента*/').on('keyup', '#val-fortune-1' ,function(){
    $('#sumBuy').text($(this).val());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще то меняется.

http://jsfiddle.net/wanchucha/VcdMk/

Comment: Проблема в том, что HTML добавлен через JS, с обычным элементом добавленным изначально все хорошо, а как быть с тем, что добавлено в процессе?